# How to make a select statement PDO and end up with $row['field']

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make a php PDO select statement and end up with the possibility to place `$row['field']` wherever I want.

In normal mysql I would have done as following:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1234'"));
```

And then I would be able to place `$row['name']` in one place and `$row['items']` in another.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1234'");
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['field'];
```

Comment: I can't give you thumbs up.. But I KNEW that it would be that difficult... Thank you so much!

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: On StackOverflow, the equivalent of a "thumbs up" is an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up); if an answer solves your problem, you should also [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

The PDO counterpart to `mysql_fetch_array` is `fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`. If you only care about an associative array, you can use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

I suggest you read up this short tutorial that will get you up and running with PDO rather quickly: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: I can't give you thumbs up.. But I KNEW that it would be that difficult... Thank you so much!